# mongodb - view the collection in a table format

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to Mongodb and I am trying to understand it. Its not conventional RDBMS. So I created a collections by using the below statement

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
   { item: "journal", qty: 25, size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" },
   { item: "notebook", qty: 50, size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, status: "A" },
   { item: "paper", qty: 100, size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, status: "D" },
   { item: "planner", qty: 75, size: { h: 22.85, w: 30, uom: "cm" }, status: "D" },
   { item: "postcard", qty: 45, size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" }
]);
```

Now if I want to see the data in the "inventory" collection I used below query.

```
db.inventory.find()
```

I can able to see data but its too clumsy. Is there a way to view the data in a table format? Like in RDBMS? if not in shell? is there a python library to prettify the look in a table.

Comment: Use [`.pretty()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.pretty/) cursor method

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be view in table format, all you need is to use the python's pandas package.

```
import pandas as pd

inventory_data = [data for data in db.inventory.find()]
df_inventory_data = pd.DataFrame(inventory_data)
print(df_inventory_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a tool like Robot-3t. You can set the default view mode to "Table mode".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is way to go in python, as outlined by another contributor.

If you want to see the data in a more "traditional" format, use a tool like MongoDB Compass, Studio 3T, or Nosqlclient.

With regards the data being "clumsy", if you want to get on well with mongodb, then you will need to get used to the JSON format. Use db.inventory.findOne() or db.inventory.find().pretty() to prettify the output.